# I'd like to have play bar visible all the time but is only visible when hover

Tags: javascript, html, audio, equalizer

Hi I'd like to have play bar visible all the time but is only visible when hover, can somebody guide me where to modify the script thank you. I'm at the moment in college but they dont teach anything useful, so I have to do it on my own sorry english is not my language

```
    $("#equalizer audio")();

equalizer.hover(function(){
    $("#equalizer audio").fadeIn(400);
},function(){
    $("#equalizer audio").(400);
});

var i = 0;

$(".equalizer_bar").each(function(index) {

  for( var j=0;j<n_components_per_bar;j++)
  {  

       $(this).append("<div class='equalizer_bar_component' id='bar_"+i+"_component_"+j+"'></div>");

  }

  $(".equalizer_bar_component",this).reverseOrder();

  i++;
});
```

Comment: Looks like someone is not reading the code they're copy/pasting.

Comment: I'm new to javascript and i didn't now chow to change it is not my fault that my college sucks and I dont have decent practice, but thanks anyway peace!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
$("#equalizer audio")();

equalizer.hover(function(){
    $("#equalizer audio").fadeIn(400);
},function(){
    $("#equalizer audio").(400);
});
```

with:

```
$("#equalizer audio").show();
```